# Using Adblock IE

Tags: internet-explorer-8, adblock

Does anyone know how to make Adblock IE work?  I installed it, and then...nothing.  How do I get it to block ads?  I'm using Internet Explorer 8.

Adblock IE: http://adblockie.codeplex.com/

Thanks.

Comment: A quick search turned up more than one thing with that name. Where'd you get yours from and what version of IE are you running?

Comment: I added these details to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computer needed to be rebooted.  Now it seems to work.

Comment: How do you like it? Is it easy to use? Any input is welcomed.

Comment: To tell the truth, I really don't use IE that much.  I just wanted to check it out before recommending it to my grandmother, since she likes IE better, but gets confused by ads.  It seems to do at least okay, no complaints, on SuperUser and download.com.